# No ejecuta el evento en Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo un inconveniente con Tkinter para que se ejecute el movimiento del polígono con las flechas del cursor, no me genera error, pero tampoco se ejecuta.

Mi código es:

```
from tkinter import *
tk = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(tk, width=400, height=400)
canvas.pack()
canvas.create_polygon(10,10,10,60,50,35)
def movertriangulo(evento):
    if event.keysym == 'Up':
        canvas.move(1,0,-3)
    elif event.keysym == 'Down':
        canvas.move(1,0,3)
    elif event.keysym == 'Left':
        canvas.move(1,-3,0)
    elif event.keysym == 'Right':
        canvas.move(1,3,0)


canvas.bind_all('Up',movertriangulo)
canvas.bind_all('Down',movertriangulo)
canvas.bind_all('Left',movertriangulo)
canvas.bind_all('Right',movertriangulo)
```

Agradezco orientación. Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vamos por partes:

- Primero de todo estás especificando mal el evento, el nombre del evento tiene que estar entre paréntesis angulares:

  ```
  '<Up>'
  ```

  Puedes ver la sitaxis correcta en la [documentación de Tkinter](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm#events).
- A al función `movertriangulo` la defines asi: `def movertriangulo(evento)` pero dentro de ella usas el parámetro `event` no `evento`, debes corregir esto.
- Esto no es un error en sí pero si una **muy mala práctica**, importas el módulo de la forma:

  ```
   from tkinter import *
  ```

  Esto es peligroso y no debe hacerse nunca. Te puedes encontrar con sorpresas desagradables y bugs difíciles de encontrar, sobretodo con códigos extensos y librerias complejas. Usa en su lugar alguna de estas fórmulas:

  ```
  import tkinter
  from tkinter import Tk, Camvas
  import tkinter as tk
  ```
- No inicias el mainloop de tu aplicación, si usas el IDLE se ejecuta correctamente porque el propio IDLE usa Tkinter, por lo que tiene un mainloop propio. Si lo lanzas desde la consola o desde otro lado que no sea el IDLE la aplicación no iniciará.

El código quedaría asi:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=400, height=400)
canvas.pack()
canvas.create_polygon(10,10,10,60,50,35)

def movertriangulo(event):
    if event.keysym == 'Up':
        canvas.move(1,0,-3)
    elif event.keysym == 'Down':
        canvas.move(1,0,3)
    elif event.keysym == 'Left':
        canvas.move(1,-3,0)
    elif event.keysym == 'Right':
        canvas.move(1,3,0)


canvas.bind_all('<Up>',movertriangulo)
canvas.bind_all('<Down>',movertriangulo)
canvas.bind_all('<Left>',movertriangulo)
canvas.bind_all('<Right>',movertriangulo)

root.mainloop()
```

Otra opción es implementar una función por cada evento:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=400, height=400)
canvas.pack()
canvas.create_polygon(10,10,10,60,50,35)

def izquierda(event):
    canvas.move(1,-3,0)

def derecha(event):
    canvas.move(1,3,0)

def abajo(event):
    canvas.move(1,0,3)

def arriba(event):
    canvas.move(1,0,-3)

canvas.bind_all('<Up>',arriba)
canvas.bind_all('<Down>',abajo)
canvas.bind_all('<Left>',izquierda)
canvas.bind_all('<Right>',derecha)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: excelente respuesta, qda claro la causa de mi error, lo curioso es q a Jesus Conde en su curso de python para niños le funciona con ese codigo del error, ??? de formas agradezco tu respuesta importante para novatos como yo.

Comment: @Jsierra2017, si te refieres al video 53, observa como los eventos que se le pasan a `bind_all` usan paréntesis angulares en todo momento, al final termina usando el evento `<keyPress>`.